# Disabling checkbox with one way binding

Tags: angularjs

I have one checkbox list. I need to disable all elements which have model value set to false initially. But because of two way binding I have a problem when I deselect one checkbox it becomes disabled. How to solve it?

```
<div class="item-s" ng-repeat="element in model.elements">
    <input id="element{{$index.toString()}}"
        type="checkbox"
        ng-true-value="true"
        ng-false-value="false"
        ng-model="element.value"
        ng-disabled="!element.value" />
    <label for="element{{$index.toString()}}">{{element.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or Plunker example? Thanks.

Comment: But basically, if you can set another property in element such as element.initValue, you can set ng-disabled="!element.initValue"

Comment: @Hoyen, I know that. But creating all double fields just because of it doesn't seem like a good idea. I thought there must be something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `::` in front of a binding expression causes it to only be evaluated once. This should get you what you need:

```
ng-disabled="::!element.value"
```

Here's [Angular's docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding) on one-time binding.

Answer (score -1):

Try using ng-init:

```
<div id="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div class="item-s" ng-repeat="element in model.elements">
        <input id="element{{$index.toString()}}" type="checkbox" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="element.value" ng-init="initValue = element.value" ng-disabled="initValue==false" />
        <label for="element{{$index.toString()}}">{{element.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jz65o9tv/

Comment: According to [Angular's documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), you should only use `ng-init` with `ng-repeat` to alias special properties.